# Changing option in dropdown via Javascript issue

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the options in a dropdown menu via a script - however nothing seems to happen. No errors either.

Here is the script:

```
javascript:
var objDropDownMenuName = document.getElementsByName("jjoprs")[0];
function writeText(form) {
    $(objDropDownMenuName.options[1]).selected = true;
    $(objDropDownMenuName).change();
}
writeText(this.form);
```

Here is the html of the form:

```
<select name='jjoprs' class='select2'>
                          <option value='NULL' selected> </option>
                          <option value='1060'>Sofi, Laco</option>
<option value='5160'>Vandrlka, Edo</option>
                             </select>
```

Thanks!

Edit: I am executing this script in IE8

Comment: Offtopic, but it would be better to give the select an ID and use `document.getElementById('idHere')`, its much more efficient to select things by ID

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't use an ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function writeText(form) {
    objDropDownMenuName.options[1].selected = true;
    $(objDropDownMenuName).change();
}
```

The jQuery selector isnt needed to set an option selected

---

Since you have jQuery:

```
 function writeText(form) {
     $('select[name="jjoprs"]')
         .find('options:nth-child(2)').attr('selected',true)
         .closest('form').submit();
  }
```

Comment: Hi Martijn, if I don't use the `.change` function, the data is not saved in our system.

Comment: I've uncommented it again :) Thought you might've added it to make the select change.

Comment: Thanks, but nothing happens in this case either. @Kolink version works, however I can't get it to save.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FadXB/ this does exactly what you ask :) I understand you want the form to submit afterwards?

Comment: Hey Martin.... your original script worked ;) The second one did not. The reason why your original script didn't work for me originally was because I forgot to execute `writeText(this.form);` at the end. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: For those wondering what the working script it, here it is: `var objDropDownMenuName = document.getElementsByName('jjoprs')[0];
function writeText(form) {
    objDropDownMenuName.options[1].selected = true;
    $(objDropDownMenuName).change();
}
writeText(this.form);`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the correct method:

```
var sel = document.getElementsByName('jjoprs')[0];
sel.selectedIndex = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, however I get an error when I try to run this `sel.change();`

Comment: That's because `sel` is not a jQuery object.